# Number of prime numbers in a range

Tags: functions, prime-numbers

Is there any function to evaluate the number of prime numbers between `[2, n]`?

For example, consider the following range: `[2, 20]`. In this case the number of prime numbers between `2` and `20` is `8`: `2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19`.
Therefore the function I'm looking for would return 8.

Also, is there any function to evaluate the number of prime numbers between `[x, y]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some [formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Algorithms_for_evaluating_.CF.80.28x.29) but the best we have so far is only asymptotic estimates.

It is shown that if we denote with $\pi(n)$ the number of primes that do not exceed $n$ then the fraction
$$\frac{\pi(n)lnn}{n}$$ can be arbitrarily close to $1$.
This is the famous [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem).

Comment: Not true. There are lots of formulas which give better errors than that of the original log-version of PNT as well as some formulas giving _exact_ values of $\pi(n)$.

Comment: not "can be arbitrarily close to 1", but "the limit for n->infinity is 1".

Answer (score 1):

For a reasonably fast method (substantially faster than finding all the primes) thanks to Meissel, Lehmer, Lagarias, Miller (who I saw posting on math.stackexchange recently) and Odlyzko, see

http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1996-65-213/S0025-5718-96-00674-6/S0025-5718-96-00674-6.pdf

For a not quite so fast but easier method by Legendre see

http://programmingpraxis.com/2011/07/22/counting-primes-using-legendres-formula/

Usually the function denoting the number of primes <= n is denoted as π (n). The number of primes in the interval [x, y] with x <= y is obviously π (y) - π (x - 1).

Answer (score 1):

Number of primes between $[1,n]$ can be evaluate with $\frac{n}{\ln n}$

Number of primes between $[x,y]$ can be evaluate with $\frac{y}{\ln y}-\frac{x}{\ln x}$